# I/me (a spy) [What is the grammatical difference?]

Tags: difference, pronouns

From Chapter 19 of Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban by J. K. Rowling:

> "Innocent, but scared!" squealed Pettigrew. "If Voldemort's supporters were after me, it was because I put one of their best men in Azkaban -- the spy, Sirius Black!"
> Black's face contorted.
> "How dare you," he growled, sounding suddenly like the bearsized dog he had been. "**I, a spy** for Voldemort? When did I ever sneak around people who were stronger and more powerful than myself? But you, Peter -- I'll never understand why I didn't see you were the spy from the start. You always liked big friends who'd look after you, didn't you? It used to be us. . . me and Remus. . . and James. . . "
> Pettigrew wiped his face again; he was almost panting for breath.
> "**Me, a spy**. . . must be out of your mind. . . never. . . don't know how you can say such a --"

What is the difference between "*I, a spy*" and "*Me, a spy*"?

Comment: The speaker is referring to him- or herself as the subject of the sentence, so **I** is correct. (They mean "I am not a spy".)

Comment: My question was what is the difference between "I, a spy" and "me, a spy"? Is the latter one informal and former one formal?

Comment: If "Me, a spy" is also part of the speech, perhaps the speaker means "Are you calling me a spy?", "To think of me being a spy!" or similar.

Comment: I don't know how British speakers feel, but in America the former is laughably formal.

Comment: I think we need more context here to understand where the two phrases come from. Can you edit to provide that?